# Google Cloud Storage To Google Cloud SQL (Postgres) Operator in Airflow (or Composer)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to load data from a CSV file in GCS, but there is no predefined operator that does this in Airflow.

I built a simple operator using a PSQL hook and a GCS file reader, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution for this, as right now the way the custom operator workes is running on a loop, row by row, a series of "INSERT INTO" statements with the open GCS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is no operator to insert data from GCS into CLoud SQL, but you can use the CloudSqlHook, to [import the GCS file](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_sql_hook.py#L312).

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/instances/import#python) you find an example for body, which is a dict contains your file rows, if your file is too big, you can import it in batchs (1k-10K rows) which is much better than a loop with `INSERT INTO`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloudSQLImportInstanceOperator on your use case. It imports data from Cloud Storage(CSV file) into a Cloud SQL instance. You can go to this [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/cloud_sql/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.cloud_sql.CloudSQLImportInstanceOperator) for an in-depth explanation about this operator.

```
import datetime

from airflow import models
from airflow.operators import bash
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.cloud_sql import CloudSQLImportInstanceOperator

# If you are running Airflow in more than one time zone
# see https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/timezone.html
# for best practices
YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

PROJECT_ID = "project-id"
DAG_ID = "cloudsql"
#BUCKET_NAME = f"{DAG_ID}_{ENV_ID}_bucket"
INSTANCE_NAME = "instance-name"

import_body = {
  "importContext": {
    "uri": "gs://bucket/file.csv",    
      "fileType": "CSV",
    "csvImportOptions": {
      "table": "table",
      "columns": [
        "column1",        
          "column2"              
      ]          
    },    
      "database": "guestbook",    
      "importUser": "postgres"      
  }
}

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Composer Example',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
}


with models.DAG(
        'composer_quickstart',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1)) as dag:

    # Print the dag_run id from the Airflow logs
   sql_import_task = CloudSQLImportInstanceOperator(
    body=import_body, instance=INSTANCE_NAME, task_id='sql_import_task', project_id=PROJECT_ID)

sql_import_task
```